# How dependency graph works in Koin or Kodein?

Tags: android, koin, kodein

I have Android/kotlin multi-module project. Some of my modules are Singletone, such as Network and Analytics modules. They need Application context in order to be initialized.

I am able to initialize Koin/Kodein in `app` module. However, the problem is how to `inject` application context into each module (since app module is not visible to Network/Analytics modules).

Basically, my app module is deoendent to other modules only.

As I recently started my project, I am evaluating Koin and Kodein to see which one is helping me the way I want. That's why I am open to switch them.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @SalomonBRYS, My issue is not code dependent. That's why I didn't put any code. Let's assume that I have these modules: app, Analytics and Network. App module depends on the rest and the rest no need dependency. I create a node (in DI) that holds app context. How Network and Analytics able to get context?

Answer (score 0):

Here is no dependency graph built like in Dagger: no code generation, no reflection - all is just function-bound.

Application context is available through [`androidContext()`](https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/documentation/koin-android/index.html#_getting_android_context_inside_a_module) method.

Modules mutual dependencies logic is described [here](https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/documentation/koin-core/index.html#_modules_namespaces).